# How to configure elasticsearch watcher with slack

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, elasticsearch-plugin, slack

I'm trying to configure ES notifications with slack. This is what I'm putting into elasticsearch.yml, taking it from the documentation on the elasticsearch site.

```
xpack.notification.slack:
  account: sam@example.com
    monitoring:
      url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
```

The error I get back is:

```
Exception in thread "main" SettingsException[Failed to load settings from /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml]; nested: MarkedYAMLException[mapping va$
Oct 27 13:34:56  elasticsearch[8290]:  in 'reader', line 99, column 15:
Oct 27 13:34:56  elasticsearch[8290]:  monitoring:
Oct 27 13:34:56  elasticsearch[8290]:            ^
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
xpack.notification.slack:
  account:
    monitoring:
      url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
```

Comment: Is that the only thing you added or did you add other stuff to your above configuration?